# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' even through installed pycryptodome

Tags: python-3.x, macos, apple-m1, pdm

When I need to import Crypto in Python3.10 like this in macOS 13.4 with M1 chip:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_pksc1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

shows:

```
Unresolved reference 'Crypto'
```

I have already tried to install `pycryptodome` like this:

```
pdm add pycryptodome
```

still could not fixed this problem. What should I do to fixed this issue?This is the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = ""
version = ""
description = ""
authors = [
    {name = "JiangXiaoqiang", email = "jiangting@gmail.com"},
]
dependencies = [
    "pycryptodome>=3.19.0",
]
requires-python = ">=3.10"
readme = "README.md"
license = {text = "MIT"}
```

this is the `pdm list` output:

```
> pdm list|grep py
Inside an active virtualenv /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/dolphin/visa/venv, reusing it.
Set env var PDM_IGNORE_ACTIVE_VENV to ignore it.
│ rdpywheel                  │ 0.1.16      │          │
│ python-dateutil            │ 2.8.2       │          │
│ pyasn1                     │ 0.5.0       │          │
│ pycryptodome               │ 3.19.0      │          │
│ openpyxl                   │ 3.1.2       │          │
│ pycparser                  │ 2.21        │          │
│ numpy                      │ 1.26.1      │          │
│ pyOpenSSL                  │ 21.0.0      │          │
│ python-dotenv              │ 1.0.0       │          │
│ pycurl                     │ 7.45.2      │          │
│ brotlipy                   │ 0.7.0       │          │
│ pyparsing                  │ 3.0.9       │          │
```

this is the UI about how I facing issue:

[image]

this is the python which output:

```
> which python
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/PycharmProjects/pythonLearn/venv/bin/python
```

and this is the pdm info output:

```
> pdm info
PDM version:
  2.10.1
Python Interpreter:
  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/PycharmProjects/pythonLearn/.venv/bin/python (3.10)
Project Root:
  /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/PycharmProjects/pythonLearn
Local Packages:
```

Comment: You get that error by running which command ? Can you give a complete minimal example ?

Comment: I get this errror in PyCharm, this is already the minimal example with the main.

Comment: When you run the script in PyCharm, does it run fine ?

Comment: no, I could not fun fine.

Comment: In the Terminal where you run `pdm add pycryptodome`, can you run the script ?

Comment: I have already run this command for many times. still could not work.

Comment: Can you post the result of `which python` and `pdm info` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_pksc1_v1_5, try the more explicit import:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_pksc1_v1_5
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but still did not fixed this issue.

Comment: hmm make sure to go through all common mistakes like checking the path, trying a different version of python and Cryptodome, check if the virtual environment is active, look if the package is even listed using `pdm list
`  @Dolphin